# Where is my ("real"/active) grub.cfg?

Tags: boot, grub2

I'm trying to update to a newer kernel, but have run into some problems - the grub.cfg which is present in /boot/grub/ and which references the new kernel, is not the grub menu that is shown during (re)boot. (When editing grub.cfg using f. ex. ukuu or grub config, it is the /boot/grub/grub.cfg that is being edited.)

As an example, at startup I can choose 4.4.0-93 as latest, but in /boot there is 4.18.10-041810 (among others), and which is referenced to in grub.cfg. (This is what I see at boot, when selecting advanced boot: http://i67.tinypic.com/8ysz9c.jpg)

/etc/default/grub is unedited, and I've tried running update-grub which completes w/o errors.

I've looked for another instance of grub.cfg using locate, but have not found it (except one in /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/ which I think references /boot/grub/grub.cfg. What am I missing?

(I'm running ubuntu 16.04.)

Comment: No Bagels what is your method of adding a newer kernel, generally speaking?  You've mentioned several things including ukuu, etc

Comment: Numerous people have commented re: the kernel.  Some of the comments say you should keep an older kernel(or two) as backup; you have five kernels still listed in grub.  Yet the 4.18.xxx kernel is not showing?  Is this what you are questioning, how can I boot using the 4.18.xxx kernel?? Also what are you running for Ubuntu, example I am still using 16.04 are you running a later version such as 18.04?

Comment: @ThomasByers I've tried using both ukuu and manually downloading from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and then dkpg:ing. And yes, I'd like to boot 4.18.xxx, but also to understand why/how the grub 2 menu at boot does not correspond to grub.cfg.. (I'm using ubuntu 16.04.)

Comment: As a baseline, type into the terminal...  uname -a and report what you see there

Comment: No Bagels here is a link from the Ubuntu community which may prove helpful to you.  Pay particular attention to the first paragraph, and then, read on!  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

Comment: 1. you DON'T manually edit grub.cfg, 2. you have too many old kernels still installed, 3. "grub config" has probably made a mess of your grub configuration (reinstall grub), 4. use `sudo update-grub`, 5. see the previous link on how to remove old kernels.

Comment: @ThomasByers uname -r : 4.4.0-92-generic 
Re: Removing old kernels, I've read that, and followed it. Space on /boot/efi is no problem according to df -h. However, all kernels downloaded by ukuu are stored in /boot .. could it have something to do with EFI?

Comment: @heynnema 1. I have not done so. 2. The picture shown in my original post does not reflect what kernels I have installed (at least not what's in /boot and/or shown in f. ex. ukuu), and neither what should be shown according to /boot/grub/grub.cfg. Nevertheless, it is what I see when I reboot. That is part of the problem. Could it have something to do with (non-?)EFI boot? 3-4. Possible. I will try this. 5. See answer to Thomas.